# My iterator returns only keys not items upon printing

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I am implementing my custom iterator for a dictionary but all I get only keys not items. My code is:

```
initial_song_data = {
"blue-da-ba-dee-sample.ogg": {
    "album": "Rush of Blood to the Head",
    "path": "blue-da-ba-dee-sample.ogg",
    "name": "blue da ba dee sample",
    "artists": ["Coldplay", "Nirvana"]
},
"to-bring-you-my-love.ogg": {
    "album": "Rush of Blood to the Head",
    "path": "to-bring-you-my-love.ogg",
    "name": "to bring you my love",
    "artists": ["Nirvana", "U2"]
}}

iter_obj = iter(initial_song_data)

while True:
    try:
        element = next(iter_obj)
        print(element.values())
    except StopIteration:
        break
for song in initial_song_data:
    print(song)
```

Output:
blue-da-ba-dee-sample.ogg

to-bring-you-my-love.ogg

What am I missing here? Please help.

Comment: Your code is not correctly indented after `while True:` Please also provide desired output.

Comment: Done and now can you check?

Comment: The desired output?

Comment: What is the intention? In Python, one usually does not need to do it this way. The `while` loop is rarely used. The `for` loop may be more suitable in the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the desired output, but maybe if you replace `print(element.values())` with `print(initial_song_data[element].values())` would yield it? (or `print(initial_song_data[element].items())`, depending on what you want to get).

By the way, when I run your code (interactively using the `exec` built-in function), I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`.

Answer (score 0):

The [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function returns the iterator object of the passed argument. The iterator for a dictionary iterates through keys of the dictionary. This way it works as expected.